# models.Page.findOne(...).sort is not a function in Sequelize Express Node

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have imported the models Correctly as it is working correctly when inserting the Data but not now i want to get the page indexes using this method can anyone help me with this

```
/*
* Get Page model 
// */
router.get('/',function(req,res){

   models.Page.find({}).sort({sorting:1}).exec(function(err,pages){
    res.render('admin/pages',{
        pages:pages
    });
   });
});
```

Here is my code for Inserting the Data it is working fine i have correctly inserted the data into database

```
  models.Page.findOne({
           where :{slug:slug}
        })
                models.Page.create({
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    content: content,
                    sorting: 100
                })

                    .then((page)=>{
                        // res.json(page);  //its for printing the Input values

                    req.flash('success', 'Page added!');
                    res.redirect('/admin/pages');
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                   console.log(err);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to list all the Page objects you have in your database, the call should be like this:

```
router.get('/',function(req,res){

    models.Page.findAll({
        order: [
            ['sorting', 'ASC']
        ],
    }).then(function(pages){
        res.render('admin/pages',{
            pages:pages
        });
    }).catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
    });
});
```